# How to refresh webpage after every 5 seconds in Windows 8 Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, webview, refresh

Below is an example of a webpage which i want to have an option of refreshing it after every 5 seconds or so or maybe when a button is clicked. I just can't see any method that will refresh the page.

```
Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    webview.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a timer:

```
Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

     Dim t As Timer = New Timer()
     webview.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))

     t.Tick += New EventHandler(Timer_Tick) ''For every tick, it will call the event
     t.Interval = 5000 ''Timer will tick every 5 seconds
     t.Enabled = True  ''Enable Timer
     t.Start()    ''Starts Timer

End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick (sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    webView.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Not for Windows 8 Store but it gives me an idea on how to use. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calling navigate to the url again should do the trick, and is essentially the same thing

```
Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    webview.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
     webview.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))
End Sub
```

**EDIT: Answer Question Without Using Button Click**

Take a look [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet) for information on timers and how to use them.

Comment: That's not what exactly I am looking for! I want the webpage to refresh automatically even when user is away.